# how can I clear notifications in android studio (java)

Tags: android-studio, android-notifications, media-player, android-music-player, foreground-service

I have this media player project and I have foreground service in it which allows me to control the song through notifications even if I clear the app in the background. Everything is working fine including the controls in the notification. But...the notification just remains forever and cannot be cleared even if I try to clear it until I re-run the app or restart my phone. Please help. Tried things like setAutoCancel(true) and etc

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling

```
stopForeground()
```

?

This method takes a Boolean to indicate if you want to remove the notification as well.

Read this [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#remove-from-foreground)

Comment: No ive just used startForeground()

Comment: When i used stop foreground.. the play pause buttons jn my notification stopped working

Comment: Please post your relevant code with comments, along with editing your post to include what you have already tried, and screenshots or videos of your current situation

Comment: Also, if you already solved your problem and my answer helped you out, please mark it as Correct :)